# session.invalidate() changing Id post login but exception thrown

Tags: java, jboss, jsessionid

I Have requirement to change the jsessionID post login of the user. I have used tips given in the previous post and used the below code

```
 HttpServletRequest request = ServletContexts.getInstance().getRequest();
 session = request.getSession();
  if (!_session.isNew()) {
  session.invalidate();
  session = request.getSession();}
```

But I am getting an exception mentioned below.

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/iptnms]] (http-/0.0.0.0:8543-1) JBWEB000211: Session event listener threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Please end the HttpSession via org.jboss.seam.web.Session.instance().invalidate()
at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Lifecycle.endSession(Lifecycle.java:267) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.contexts.ServletLifecycle.endSession(ServletLifecycle.java:187) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.sessionDestroyed(SeamListener.java:59) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:681) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:644) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.invalidate(StandardSession.java:1092) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.invalidate(StandardSessionFacade.java:150) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at com.redback.nsm.security.login.action.LoginAction.sessionChange(LoginAction.java:145) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:79) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.bpm.BusinessProcessInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BusinessProcessInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.core.SynchronizationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SynchronizationInterceptor.java:35) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:196) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:114) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at com.redback.nsm.security.login.action.LoginAction_$$_javassist_seam_13.sessionChange(LoginAction_$$_javassist_seam_13.java) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335) [jboss-el.jar:1.0_02.CR6]
at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:280) [jboss-el.jar:1.0_02.CR6]
at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59) [jboss-el.jar:1.0_02.CR6]
at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:67) [jboss-el.jar:1.0_02.CR6]
at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186) [jboss-el.jar:1.0_02.CR6]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.1.24.jar:2.1.24]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jsf-api-2.1.24.jar:2.1]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jsf-api-2.1.24.jar:2.1]
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:170) [jsf-api-2.1.24.jar:2.1]
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:284) [jsf-api-2.1.24.jar:2.1]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205) [jsf-impl-2.1.24.jar:2.1.24]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355) [jsf-impl-2.1.24.jar:2.1.24]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164) [jsf-impl-2.1.24.jar:2.1.24]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877) [jsf-api-2.1.24.jar:2.1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1826) [jsf-api-2.1.24.jar:2.1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822) [jsf-api-2.1.24.jar:2.1]
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168) [jsf-api-2.1.24.jar:2.1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847) [jsf-api-2.1.24.jar:2.1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1819) [jsf-api-2.1.24.jar:2.1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822) [jsf-api-2.1.24.jar:2.1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822) [jsf-api-2.1.24.jar:2.1]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:447) [jsf-impl-2.1.24.jar:2.1.24]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124) [jsf-impl-2.1.24.jar:2.1.24]
at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamViewHandler.renderView(SeamViewHandler.java:188) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286) [jsf-api-2.1.24.jar:2.1]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.1.24.jar:2.1.24]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.24.jar:2.1.24]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.24.jar:2.1.24]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jsf-api-2.1.24.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at com.redback.nsm.ui.SessionInvalidatorFilter.doFilter(SessionInvalidatorFilter.java:217) [classes:]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:78) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.CR1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:420) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.web.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:466) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```

I am using a JSF based web application with Jboss as the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the Below and its working good.
HttpServletRequest request = ServletContexts.getInstance().getRequest();
    HttpSession oldSession = request.getSession();

```
Enumeration attrNames = oldSession.getAttributeNames();
Properties props = new Properties();

if (attrNames != null)
{
  while (attrNames.hasMoreElements())
  {
    String key = (String) attrNames.nextElement();
    props.put(key, oldSession.getAttribute(key));
  }
  // Invalidating previous session
  oldSession.invalidate();
  // Generate new session
  HttpSession newSession = request.getSession(true);
  attrNames = props.keys();
  while (attrNames.hasMoreElements())
  {
    String key = (String) attrNames.nextElement();
    newSession.setAttribute(key, props.get(key));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the jsessionID post login of the user,try like below

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
   if(!session ==null){ 
    session.invalidate();
    session = request.getSession();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks your answer was partially helpful.